# "Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed" when using command --livereload ionic/angular on real device android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, livereload

My ionic/angular app works perfectly ON REAL ANDROID DEVICE when running `ionic cordova run android --device`. But when running `ionic cordova run android --device --livereload` it won't work. I've tried every workaround on the web, nothing seems to fix the error.

Already checked my ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH as suggested here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1354

serve-config.js

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATHS = [
    path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www'),
    path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www')
];
```

- 

/node_modules/ @ionic/ app-scripts/ dist/ dev-server/ live-reload.d.ts/ live-reload.d.ts

```
import { ServeConfig } from './serve-config';
export declare function createLiveReloadServer(config: ServeConfig): void;
export declare function injectLiveReloadScript(content: any, host: string, port: Number): any;
```

- 

node_modules/ @ionic/ app-scripts/ dist/ dev-server/ live-reload.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var logger_diagnostics_1 = require("../logger/logger-diagnostics");
var path = require("path");
var tinylr = require("tiny-lr");
var events = require("../util/events");
function createLiveReloadServer(config) {
    var liveReloadServer = tinylr();
    liveReloadServer.listen(config.liveReloadPort, config.host);
    function fileChange(changedFiles) {
        // only do a live reload if there are no diagnostics
        // the notification server takes care of showing diagnostics
        if (!logger_diagnostics_1.hasDiagnostics(config.buildDir)) {
            liveReloadServer.changed({
                body: {
                    files: changedFiles.map(function (changedFile) { return '/' + path.relative(config.wwwDir, changedFile.filePath); })
                }
            });
        }
    }
    events.on(events.EventType.FileChange, fileChange);
    events.on(events.EventType.ReloadApp, function () {
        fileChange([{ event: 'change', ext: '.html', filePath: 'index.html' }]);
    });
}
exports.createLiveReloadServer = createLiveReloadServer;
function injectLiveReloadScript(content, host, port) {
    var contentStr = content.toString();
    var liveReloadScript = getLiveReloadScript(host, port);
    if (contentStr.indexOf('/livereload.js') > -1) {
        // already added script
        return content;
    }
    var match = contentStr.match(/<\/body>(?![\s\S]*<\/body>)/i);
    if (!match) {
        match = contentStr.match(/<\/html>(?![\s\S]*<\/html>)/i);
    }
    if (match) {
        contentStr = contentStr.replace(match[0], liveReloadScript + "\n" + match[0]);
    }
    else {
        contentStr += liveReloadScript;
    }
    return contentStr;
}
exports.injectLiveReloadScript = injectLiveReloadScript;
function getLiveReloadScript(host, port) {
    var src = "//" + host + ":" + port + "/livereload.js?snipver=1";
    return "  <!-- Ionic Dev Server: Injected LiveReload Script -->\n  <script src=\"" + src + "\" async=\"\" defer=\"\"></script>";
}
```

- 

```
   $ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.12.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : 5.0.4, android 7.1.4, browser
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (23 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.2
   native-run  : 1.2.2

System:

   NodeJS : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Linux 5.4
```

---

ERROR DESCRIPTION in browser

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:17748)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "4.4.6",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/hotspot": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "android-versions": "^1.5.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.11.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cleartext": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-hotspot": "^1.2.10",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.10",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/moment-round": "^1.0.3",
    "moment-round": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "imagepicker para PSDigital"
      },
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-hotspot": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cleartext": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```